# Change target site

Tags: drush

I installed Drupal 7 manually and later installed Drush 5. That works fine. When I use command **drush config** it shows the path to my site.
Now I have installed a second instance of Drupal 7 in another site location. How do I change the drush installation to point to the new site rather than the old one? I have spend an hour searching documentation but I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Drush is detecting site location automatically based on the current working directory and site alias. Just move to the site directory or use `--root` option to point the desired site to operate.

Also, note that Drush 5 is very outdated version. For Drupal 7 you should install Drush 8.

Comment: Thanks for help. Working now thanks to using -r option as you suggest. I am using CiviCRM and Drush 8 didn't seem to have the CiviCRM commands. Did I miss something?